# NavigationBar Height getting wrong value xamarin forms android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

NavigationBar Height getting wrong value xamarin forms android
 public int GetHeight()

```
    {
        int statusBarHeight = -1;
        int resourceId = Activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0)
        {
            statusBarHeight = Activity.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return statusBarHeight;
    }
```

I thing its not getting proper value
how to get proper Navigation Bar height?

Answer (score 0):

With `"status_bar_height"` you are querying the height of the status bar, which is the part above the navigation bar (the bit containing the notification and system icons, [see here](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#status-bar)). You'll have to use `"navigation_bar_height"` ([see here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/346537/#Comment_346537)).

**Disclaimer:** While literally answering your question, this might well be something different from what you want. The Android Navigation Bar is the bar that's usually at the bottom, containing the *back*, *home* and *overview* buttons ([see here](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#android-navigation-bar)).

On Android you have the possibility to get the height of the bar with the `GetBarHeight(IPlatformElementConfiguration<Android,NavigationPage>)` extension ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.platformconfiguration.androidspecific.appcompat.navigationpage.getbarheight?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_PlatformConfiguration_AndroidSpecific_AppCompat_NavigationPage_GetBarHeight_Xamarin_Forms_IPlatformElementConfiguration_Xamarin_Forms_PlatformConfiguration_Android_Xamarin_Forms_NavigationPage__)), which can be used like

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>.GetBarHeight()
```

from the code behind of your navigation page.

Comment: its also getting wrog value navigation_bar_height ,using status_bar_height I am gettiing 72 and using navigation_bar_heigh I am getting 130,nut I my Navigation bar is smaller than this values